# Answering a questions train of thought

Tags: discussion

I'm new to Stackoverflow and it's simple to see how to answer a question.
But sometimes I just want to add 2 cents to someone else's answer.  You've seen it:

## 6 - Best Answer Ever

`@Steve- I heard the solution on slashdot when they said the world was ending.

@Joe- ThinkGeek was selling the plush pillows.

I would like to say something here but don't know how`

Comment: Shouldn't this be in meta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your reputation to 50.

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Answer (score 2):

We intentionally prevent people with [under 50 reputation from posting comments](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) because they are unfamiliar with how the site works and tend to post useless comments like those in your example.

If you post comments like `+1 best answer ever`, they will be flagged for removal and deleted by a moderator. This is just noise, something we're trying to keep down on Stack Overflow in order to faciliate focus on the useful content in the form of answers.

If you have something useful to contribute, you should post it as an answer. If not, there's no need to say anything. Thanks to [inflation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation), your 2 cents isn't even worth 2 cents anymore.